# Android: How can i convert a Bitmap array to Int array?

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap, int, drawable

I'm cutting some images of int array...

```
int[] imagenes_originales = new int[] {
    R.drawable.image1,
    R.drawable.image2,
    R.drawable.image3,
    R.drawable.image4
}

int[] new_images;

for (a = 0; a <= 3; a++) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imagenes_originales[a]);

    int x = bitmap.getWidth(), y = bitmap.getHeight();
    int escalax = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    Bitmap recorte = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, y / 2, escalax, 100);
}
```

How can I convert the Bitmap images in my `new_images[]` variable?

Comment: Could you explain more details, I don't understand what you really want, what is the purpose at all?

Comment: What do you want new_images to hold in the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imagenes_originales[a]);
int x = bitmap.getWidth();
int y = bitmap.getHeight();
int[] intArray = new int[x * y];
bitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, x, 0, 0, x, y);
```

Your bitmap to int array is now in `intArray`/